# How to change border color of :webkit-scrollbar-thumb?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

[Click this link to view the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OYwT.png)

I want to add a colored border to the scroll bar thumb.

Comment: You should not post code as an image. see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Carson Yeah, I was trying to do that but it was throwing me some error

Answer (score 1):

Move the `border` style from `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` to `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 3px solid #00e5ff;
}
```